# search and replace double space

Tags: regular-expressions, search, replace

I've only recently started using emacs, for professional reasons.
I'm trying to replace all double spaces in a text file by single ones using regex.
In `C-M-s` the expression `\s-\{2\}` matches two spaces all right but also more which I don't want.
And in a search and replace query the same expression doesn't match anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to use interactively is this: `\s-\{2\}`, not this: `\s-\\{2\\}`.

That works for me, for both `C-M-s` (`isearch-forward-regexp`) and `C-M-%` (`query-replace-regexp`).

You edited your question, changing `\s-\\{2\\}` to `\s-\{2\}`.  But I don't see a problem with the latter.  It does *not* match more than two consecutive space chars, for me.  And it does match two for query-replace also, for me.

(It can be confusing to go back and forth between entering a regexp interactively and using a regexp in Lisp code. Interactively you typically do not use `\\`.)

Comment: Sorry, I made a mystake in my post.  I actually used \s-\{2\}

Comment: Then I think you'll need to give a more detailed recipe to repro the problem - step-by-step, starting from `emacs -Q`. I don't see a problem when I do that.

Comment: It works when I do C-x h and then add the regex.  So I guess it did not work because I was not selecting the whole text.  Is that it?

Comment: You should not need to select any text. It's not clear to me what you're trying. Please edit the question to provide a step-by-step recipe of what you're doing - what keys you hit etc. You should be able to just use `C-M-s` or `C-M-%` directly, providing the regexp `\s-\{2\}`. (For the replacement text for `C-M-%` just type a single space char.)

Comment: I am bit confused as well. I am new at this.  But if I put the cursor at the beginning of the buffer or before the pattern I'm looking for, it works.   Thank you for your help.

Comment: Both Isearch and query-replace look forward. So if you want to search the whole buffer then put the cursor at the beginning before searching.